# How to get category last child url for an entry

Tags: categories, entry, gwcode-categories

I'm trying to use GWcode Categories to output category last child url for an entry. Code looks like:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="products" category="{segment_2_category_id}" orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="8" status="open" paginate="bottom" dynamic="no"}

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 category-item">
        {exp:gwcode_categories group_id="1" url_title="{last_segment}" last_only="yes"}
        <a href="{site_url}{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{cat_url_title}/{url_title}">
            {product_image limit="1"}<img src="{product_image:image}" alt="{product_image:title}" class="img-responsive">{/product_image}
            <h3>{title}</h3>
        </a> 
        {/exp:gwcode_categories} 

    </div>
    {switch='|||</div><div class="row row-category">'}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

but what I'm getting is a list of all last child categories urls from the group 1.

Any clue how to get last child category url per listed entry?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, user error - fix was very easy - use entry_id instead of title_url:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="products" category="{segment_2_category_id}" orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="8" status="open" paginate="bottom" dynamic="no"}

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 category-item">
        {exp:gwcode_categories group_id="1" entry_id="{entry_id}" last_only="yes"}
        <a href="{site_url}{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{cat_url_title}/{url_title}">
            {product_image limit="1"}<img src="{product_image:image}" alt="{product_image:title}" class="img-responsive">{/product_image}
            <h3>{title}</h3>
        </a> 
        {/exp:gwcode_categories} 

    </div>
    {switch='|||</div><div class="row row-category">'}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
```